# SQL statement to get different data from the same table to a new table as columns

Tags: sql

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I have a Table 1. Example data as below. I need to create a new table based on the column values of the Table 1 using SQL. Can I use join statement. The Code XX , YY and ZZ can be used as one to one filter to populate the columns CodeAmt1, CodeAmt2 and CodeAmt3 data in New Table from Table 1.

Table 1:

| Policy | Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | XX | 10.00 |
| A | YY | 11.00 |
| A | ZZ | 13.00 |

New Table:

| Policy | CodeAmt1 | CodeAmt2 | CodeAmt3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10.00 | 11.00 | 13.00 |

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far. Also, what is the point of the first table in your question?

Comment: If you also had the row (A, WW, 14.00) in the table, would you expect a CodeAmt4 column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table then I hope you only want four columns in the new table as `policy`, `codeamt1`, `codeamt2`, `codeamt3`.

You can use conditional aggregation in your query to create your new table. I am just giving you the `SELECT` query for clarity.

```
SELECT policy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'XX' THEN amount END) AS codeamt1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'YY' THEN amount END) AS codeamt2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'ZZ' THEN amount END) AS codeamt3
  FROM your_table t
GROUP BY policy;
```

Comment: If it solved your issue then accept this answer to mark your question as resolved.